# LuaLaTeX doesn't execute plantuml with Cyrrilic-name file

Tags: graphics, luatex, shell-escape

It's derivative from my previous question: [\DeclareGraphicsRule for plantuml doesn't work with LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495276/declaregraphicsrule-for-plantuml-doesnt-work-with-lualatex)

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.tif,.svg,.puml}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}%
{%
    `convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`-tif-converted-to.png %
}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.svg}{pdf}{.pdf}%
{%
    `inkscape -D -z --file=#1 --export-pdf=`dirname #1`/`basename #1 .svg`-svg-converted-to.pdf %
}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.puml}{png}{.png}%
{%
    `pumlconvert #1 %
}

\begin{document}

    \includegraphics{пример_свг}    %svg example
    \includegraphics{пример_тифф}   %tiff example
    \includegraphics{puml_example}

    \includegraphics{диаграмма}     %puml example in Russian

\end{document}
```

`pumlconvert` is a little `bash`-script for dealing with `puml` files:

```
#!/bin/bash

PUMLFILE=$1
fname="${PUMLFILE%.*}"
PUMLCONVERTED="$fname-puml-converted-to.png"
create_png_and_rename () {
  plantuml -charset UTF-8 $PUMLFILE
  mv "$fname.png" "$PUMLCONVERTED"
}
if [ -f "$PUMLCONVERTED" ]
then
echo "$PUMLCONVERTED found."
    if [ "$PUMLFILE" -nt "$PUMLCONVERTED" ]
    then
    echo "$PUMLFILE is newer than $PUMLCONVERTED."
    create_png_and_rename
    fi
else
create_png_and_rename
echo "$PUMLCONVERTED not found."
fi
```

Everything works perfect with roman filenames. `Inkscape` and `convert` are also works well with Cyrrilic filenames. But `plantuml` haven't been executed if there non-roman letters in filename. It works well, if executed from terminal, but from `LuaLaTeX` doesn't.

What can be the problem? Why other applications deals with non-roman filenames from `LuaLaTeX`, but `plantuml` doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this string to `pumlconvert`to set locale manually:

```
LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8
```

And everything works as I want now.